# New-object, property "disappears"

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make a script returning AD users ID, Display Name and Group memberships based on an input file and export the result to another file.

However, the group membership information seems to get lost in the process.

Any ideas?

My current script:

```
$Result = @()

ForEach ($_ in gc userlist.csv)

{

$User = Get-ADUser $_ -Properties DisplayName, SamAccountName, LastLogonDate | Select DisplayName, SamAccountName, LastLogonDate
$Groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $_ | Select Name

# So far it seems to work

$Properties = @{
                UserID = (@($User.SamAccountName) -join ',')
                Name = (@($User.DisplayName) -join ',')
                LastLogonDate = (@($User.LastLogonDate) -join ',')
                Groups = (@($Groups.Name) -join ',')

                }

# By this time, Groups doesn't return any information

$Result += New-Object psobject -Property $Properties

}

$Result | Select-Object Name, UserID, Groups, LastLogonDate | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path output.csv
```

Comment: `Select-Object Medlemskap` -> `Select-Object Groups`

Comment: You're absolutely right, but even if I change it, it still doesn't return the Groups as expected.
(I translated the names to make it easier to understand and missed that one.)
Edited the code in the post.

Comment: `ForEach ($_` <-- this is not a good idea. $_ is an automatic variable and should only be used as such. Change $_ to $user or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I think might work:

```
$Result = @()

ForEach ($User in gc userlist.csv) {

    $UserDetails = Get-ADUser $User -Properties DisplayName, SamAccountName, LastLogonDate | Select DisplayName, SamAccountName, LastLogonDate
    $Groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $User | Select Name

    $Properties = @{
        UserID = $UserDetails.SamAccountName
        Name = $UserDetails.DisplayName
        LastLogonDate = $UserDetails.LastLogonDate
        Groups = ($Groups.Name -join '; ')
    }

    $Result += New-Object psobject -Property $Properties

}
$Result | Select-Object Name, UserID, Groups, LastLogonDate | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path output.csv
```

- Per my comment, although using `$_` will probably work its not particularly good practice to manually set that variable so i've changed it to $user.
- I've therefore changed your $user to $userdetails.
- I removed your casting as an array `@()` for each of the properties as well as your joining them with `,`. I'm not sure why this is necessary, except perhaps with the `Groups` property, but in order to then not confuse the CSV result, i've joined these with a `;` instead.

Comment: Hello.
I sent this script to my colleague who ran it on a 2016 server, and it worked as intended, so it might have been an issue with PS 2.0.

However, I'm marking this as the answer, as it's best practice and working :)